# В предложном падеже: "в сЕти или в сетИ"?

Tags: грамматика, орфоэпия

На форумах обсуждается "вечный вопрос" предложном падеже слова сеть: *в сЕти или в сетИ*. Орфоэпические словари разрешают оба варианта, но различаются ли они по смыслу или по стилю?

Можно ли как-то обосновать смысл и стиль, а не только полагаться на частотность употребления? Как и в каких случаях говорите вы?

Comment: Я уточнил вопрос, хотя обычно этого не делаю без явного на то мнения автора. Но тут случай для меня очевидный, ибо ни один словарь не даст для винительного множественного ударение иное, чем "в сет**и**" (Попалась рыбка в сет**и**"). Проблема возможна только с предложным падежом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vera, очень хорошо, что вопрос этот подняли. У меня все руки не доходили.
Насчет словарей. Это не совсем так. В словарях для дикторов даётся только один вариант - в сЕти. И я считаю это неправильным.

Далее. В те словари, где не различают местный и собственно предложный падежи, можно не смотреть. Но, к сожалению, других почти и нет.

На самом деле есть две формы предложного, одна отвечает главным образом предлогу О, другая - В/НА/ПРИ. Различия проявляются в словах мужского рода первого (академического, оно же второе школьное) склонения и женского третьего склонения. (*О лесе - в лесу, о ш**е**рсти - вывавлялся в шерст**и***) и т.д.

Есть случаи пограничные, есть исключения (*о полке* и *о полку [Игоревом]* - от слова "полк").

Наконец, есть отельные случаи, когда различия в падежных формах можно трактовать как смысловые различия (на д**у**хе и на дух**у**). Нечто подобное, на мой взгляд имеет место с вариантами *в сет**и** - в с**е**ти*. *Рыба в сет**и*** и *рыба в с**е**ти* имеют разное значение. Первое - прямое пространственное (трал с рыбой достали), второе - скорее переносное (попалась рыбка!) или же условное, со вторым значение слова сеть (сеть точек обслуживания, агентурная сеть и т.п.).

В компьютерном сленге второй вариант крайне маловероятен, тут почти всегда прямое понимание "где?".

//=================
Поэтому: *o с**e**ти*, *в с**е**ти [cупермаркетов, агентурной]*, но как правило - *в [компьютерной, рыболовной] сет**и***.
//=================

Сравните: 
*Говорил (о чем?) о кр**о**ви*. но: *Храм Спаса (где?) на кров**и***.
*О к**o**сти в горле", но *широк в кост**и***.
К сожалению, эти вещи часто смешивают. Поэтому и возникают те самые дискуссии.

Это тот самый редчайший случай, когда профессионалы (программисты и рыбаки) чувствуют язык лучше многих профессиональных лингвистов. В моей "коллекции" едва ли не единственный.

По поводу частотности. По телевизору все, кто старается говорить правильно (дикторы), говорят "в с**е**ти". Чем и делают большую ошибку. Какая уж тут "частотность".

(Я продолжу, если мысль не до конца понятна)

Comment: Многословно, но требует продолжения. Не является Ответом.

Comment: Интересно, а ответом-то почему не является?)))

Answer (score 1):

В технических случаях (электрическая сеть, сеть интернет, сеть магазинов) я всегда говорю "в сетИ" - это переносный смысл слова "сеть". Будь я рыбаком, возможно, время от времени рассказывал бы в сетИ о рыбе, затрепыхавшейся в моей сЕти.

Comment: В чем-то правильно, но неполно. Рыбаки тоже говорят в сетИ. А вообще - см. мой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за интересное исследование. Я о предлогах кроме "в" раньше не задумывался, поскольку не приходилось размышлять "о сети" или "для сети".

Comment: Да не за что,  для меня самого это больная тема, этот местный падеж. Там столько нюансов интересных... Но вы тут немного ошиблись. "Для сети" - это вообще другой случай, родительный падеж (чего? - кого?). Тут  разговора быть не может. Для с**е**ти.  Хотя родительный тоже хитрый, но к "с**е**ти" это отношения не имеет. Единственный падеж, где возможно ударение на последний слог - предложный. Но тоже только в определенных случаях.

Comment: behemothus, если вы имеете в виду словарь Зарвы, то надо учитывать год его издания - 2001. Тогда еще, видимо, интернет не бык так распространен , как сегодня. Видимо, авторы не учли такое ударение. Тем более, что в последних изданиях словарей ( орфоэпических не знаю, но можно поискать) даются оба варианта. Почему бы вам не заглянуть в Большой орфоэпический словарь ( издание 2012). Может, там будет такое ударение.

Comment: ">если вы имеете в виду словарь Зарвы"   Не только его. А какое именно положение вы предлагаете уточнить у Резниченко?  Или вы имеете в виду Касаткина-2012? Последнего я в сети я не видел. О нем ведь тоже отзывы хорошие и... разные.  http://www.trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=55516

Comment: Да, посмотрел, Резниченко - 2010, а Каленчук с Касаткиными - 2012 г. Но это единственное, что могу поправить в своем тексте.

Comment: А какое ударение там? Я имею виду сетИ или сЕти.

Comment: behemothus , Грамота разрешает оба варианта. И на какие дополнительные значения не указывает. То же и в словаре Лопатина.

Comment: Где грамота разрешает? А Лопатин - не авторитет по части орфоэпии.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответы. Попробую подвести итог, но требуется проверка (всё ли я правильно (или неправильно) понимаю:

ПРЯМОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ: рыболовная сеть (обычно местный падеж),  но: сеть морщин, сеть теней (обычно объектный падеж)

ПЕРЕНОСНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ: компьютерная, электрическая (местный падеж), но: сеть магазинов, учебных заведений, агентурная сеть, социальная сеть (объектный падеж).

1) В сетИ

Местный падеж (где): МЕСТО, обозначенное словом «сеть»: компьютерная, электрическая сети. Хотя они тоже состоят из отдельных объектов (отсюда следует название «сеть»), но такая сеть воспринимается КАК ЕДИНОЕ ЦЕЛОЕ.

2) В сЕти

Объектный падеж (в чем): ПРОСТРАНСТВО, состоящее из отдельных объектов (сеть магазинов, учебных заведений, агентурная сеть). Такая сеть  мыслится как множество объектов, связанных между собой, но единое целое не составляющих.

И дословно приведу ответ с другого форума (где почти всё не так:

Однозначно на этот вопрос ответить сложно, так как в разговорной речи употребляются оба варианта слов: в сЕти и в сетИ. Выбор слов зависит от контекста их употребления. Слово с ударным первым гласным "в сЕти" употребимо, если говорим: в рыболовной сЕти, в замеченной в углу сЕти паутины, в кружевной сЕти деревьев или сЕти морщинок на лице.

Если же речь идет о социальной сети в интернете, то произнесем слово с ударным окончанием: в сетИ интернета. Это форма слова является разговорной, но она уже проникла даже в некоторые словари.

Чаще употребляется падежная форма существительного в сЕти, независимо от того, рыболовная ли это сеть или сеть телевидения или радиовещания. Сама слышала, как по радио дикторы говорят : в сЕти радиовещания.
Мне импонирует больше произношение с ударным первым слогом - в сЕти.

Comment: да, примерно так я это себе и представляю. Детали я сейчас не буду по новой ворошить, они есть в моем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

С технической точки зрения, компьютерные сети (в т. ч. сеть "интернет") ничем не отличаются от телефонных сетей (те же провода, тот же принцип передачи сигнала), телевизионных и радио сетей и вообще любых сетей - точек (узлов), соединенных физическими или воображаемыми линиями.

Никто не говорит "произошел обрыв в телефонной сЕти" или "питание от электрической сЕти 220 вольт", или об "открытии нового отделения Российской федеральной почтовой сЕти" (тоже сеть, тоже для обмена сообщениями), или "о транспортной сЕти".

Поэтому если есть сомнения в том, где именно делать ударение - заменяйте "компьютерную сеть" на "телефонную сеть". Или на рыболовную, с точки зрения топологии это одно и то же.

---

Что касается "местного падежа" и "объектного падежа".
Сеть - это граф, узлы и связи между ними. Если кто-то разделяет "в компьютерной сети" (местный падеж? "единое целое, место?") и "в агентурной сети" (объектный падеж? "пространство, объект?!") - то это проблемы восприятия конкретного человека. Если нарисовать агентурную сеть на бумаге или сеть магазинов на карте, то она внезапно станет восприниматься как конкретный объект. И наоборот - если подумать что тот компьютер, за котором вы сидите - это узел сети, от него отходят связи до других узлов - то компьютерная сеть будет восприниматься как пространство, в котором вы находитесь. Можно рассматривать сеть изнутри, на уровне отдельных узлов и связей, можно смотреть на все узлы сразу - но сама сеть от этого не меняется. И падеж не меняется.

Comment: Речь об ударении в предложном падеже.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, да, вопрос про "в сети". Или вы имели в виду текст про "местный/объектный" падеж - так это из соседних ответов. Поясните пожалуйста о чем Ваш комментарий.

Comment: Простите, я не заметил сначала первую часть. С мнением Вашим всё-таки не согласен. И, признаться, не всё понимаю, поэтому не всё могу прокомментировать. И в том, что "никто не говорит", я бы так уверен не был. Слышал на Эхе Москвы ударение "в сЕти", возможно, не раз, но, к сожалению, не помню контекста.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, согласен, "никто не говорит" - это не совсем аккуратно, т.к. говорят еще и не такое. Однако идея в том, что компьютеры и радио не делают компьютерные и радио сети какими-то особенными сетями, о которых надо говорить с другой постановкой ударения.

Comment: Возможно, Ваша логика о том, что ударение должно быть одинаковым для любых сетей, и правильная, не знаю, но меня интересует, как Вы аргументируете своё утверждение о том, что только на последний слог правильно делать ударение. До сих пор Вы только сказали, что никто так не говорит, а потом поправились, что, мол, говорят, конечно, но ведь очевидно, что это неправильно. Но это только Ваше мнение, а не по-настоящему убедительные доводы. Даже если 97% так говорят, разве это означает, что они говорят правильно?

Comment: *никто не говорит "произошел обрыв в телефонной сЕти" или "питание от электрической сЕти 220 вольт"* - А вы в словарь заглядывали хоть раз прежде чем такое писать? Не загляните, в Зарву хотя бы, "Русское словесное ударение". http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x .  Это орфоэпическая норма, до недавнего времени - единственная.

Comment: *@АртёмЛуговой, согласен, "никто не говорит" - это не совсем аккуратно* - это не просто "не аккуратно", это грубое отступление от истины. Именно так и говорит большинство дикторов и вообще консервативных, следящих за правильностью речи, людей.  И не надо тут рассказывать теорию графов. Это не имеет никакого значения для орфоэпических норм. А вот значение, смысл (сиречь семантика) отношения, передаваемого предложным падежом, очень даже имеет. Вы этого просто не поняли или не захотели понять. И это у вас не проблема восприятия, это недостаток языкового чутья.

Answer (score 0):

Тот, кто ударяет ***в сети*** на *Е,* невольно употребляет мн. число от *сеть.*  Попасть в сети, т. е. оказаться в каком-либо состоянии помимо воли, совсем не то, что попасть в сеть. Церковно-славянское *сети* (пишется через *Ять* как слово особое) разумелось как тенеты, диавольские козни, искушение. А слово *сеть* в ед. числе если и встречалось бы, то только в других, широко известных мирских смыслах, и писалось бы непременно через *Е* (есть). Поэтому понять, о каком значении слова идёт речь, может помочь только контекст, а по краткой записи — и он не поможет.

Избегая путаницы, следует ударять *И.*

Comment: *Тот, кто ударяет в сети на Е, невольно употребляет мн. число от сеть.* ---- это каким же образом Вас понимать-то? Они, что совсем падежов не знают? "Попал в сЕти" - это куда, винительный, "Находится в сЕти" - это предложный. Как можно спутать не знаю.  ("Находится в сетИ" - это местная форма предложного, но это уже моё разумение).

Comment: Фраза начинается так: «В сети... ». Какой падеж? Какое число? Пробежать глазами вперёд и понять не всегда и не всем быстро удаётся. Вот и путают,—послушайте любые новостные каналы: сплошные оговорки.

Comment: *«В сети... ». Какой падеж? Какое число?*  - если так фраза начинается, то заканчивать уже не надо. ))) Неизвестно. Только у нас всё дело в том, что падеж и число известны. Единственое и предложный. И спутать тут что-то невозможно. "В речи NN я не верю". "В речи NN высказал свое мнение". Ну кто спутает-то? Не будете же требовать ударение в "речИ"? Тут другое. "В шЕрсти собаки паразитов не найдено" и "Он был весь в какой-то шерстИ, приставшей к потному телу" - это попытка передать разный смысл. Хотя и спорная, но понятная. И с сетью то же.

Comment: «На форумах обсуждается "вечный вопрос": в сЕти или в сетИ. Орфоэпические словари разрешают оба варианта, но различаются ли они по смыслу или по стилю?

Можно ли как-то обосновать смысл и стиль, а не только полагаться на частотность употребления? Как и в каких случаях говорите вы?» ======= Вот такой был и есть вопрос. "Дело в том, что падеж и число известны." — это от  behemothus, и дальше — про шерсть что-то. В вопросе нет ничего про падеж и число.

Comment: *В вопросе нет ничего про падеж и число.*  - есть. Достаточно посмотреть *в сеть* - и убедиться. Другие падежи никому не интересны, ибо там нет причин для обсуждения. *Дальше там что-то от shampar.a, но мне разбираться надоело*.

Comment: И число не интересно? Достаточно посмотреть туда же?

Comment: И число не интересно. Повторяю, речь идет о предложном/местном падеже единственного числа. Ни об одной другой форме носителю русского не придет в голову спорить серьезно.