# Выложил в соцсети или в соцсети?

Tags: лексика, орфоэпия

Как понять сообщение «Выложил в соцсети»? Выложенное находится в сетях или сети?

Поясню. Допустим, что читаете. И, допустим, — не себе одному. Всем будет одинаково очевидно число?

Answer (score 1):

ВЫЛОЖИТЬ,  что. 1. во что, на что, куда.

Выложил в соцсеть (**В.п. ед. ч.**) и выложил в соцсети (**В.п. мн. число**).

Здесь **не используется П.п.**: выложил в одной соцсети или в нескольких соцсетях.

Comment: Так ведь есть же разница между «выложил» и «положил». Или (что б понятнее): поместил в гостиницу / разместил в гостинице. Поэтому, положил в сеть, но — выложил в сети.

Comment: В толковых словарях указано: положить куда, где (П.п. и В.п.), выложить куда, во что (В.п.). Большинство пользователей пользуются этими рекомендациями и используют выражение "выложить в Сеть (В.п.)".

Comment: Спасибо, но подтекст этого вопроса: как ударить, чтобы поняли, по крайней мере, что ударил не случайно и так, как общепринято. Подправлю Вопрос.

Comment: Ударение здесь спорное. . Обсуждалось много раз. А подтекста не вижу. Я считаю, "в соцсетИ" - не только допустимым, но и желательным вариантом.  А "подтекст" надо писать явно, иначе вам будут отвечать так, как задан вопрос. Искать скрытый смысл никто особо не предрасположен.

Comment: «Выложенное находится в сетях или сети?» Здесь есть что-то скрытое?

Answer (score 0):

Никак не понять, только по контексту, если он есть, да и то вряд ли. Омонимия это.

"Выложил" у вас - где или куда? Если "где", то предложный падеж, в единственном - в социальной сети. 
Если "куда", то предложный множественного - в социальные сети.

В чем проблема?

Выяснилось, что проблема у автора - в ударении. Но это сто раз обсуждалось
[В предложном падеже: "в сЕти или в сетИ"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415543)
(Другие ссылки просто лень искать, гуглите, кому надо)

Comment: Проблема действительно в ударении. Это из вопроса ясно. По ссылкам, если и не лень, ходит не следует: ответа нет. По этой ссылке идёт обсуждение единственного числа.

Comment: Ну это как знаете. ))) Не хотите, кто ж Вас заставит-то?! Хотя если у Вас проблема еще и с множественным, которое в любом словаре есть однозначно, то ссылки и впрямь не помогут.

Comment: В вопросе: в соцсети, а не в социальной (социальные) сети.

Comment: Вы потрясающе наблюдательны. А в ответе у меня именно "социальные сети". Как раз для того, чтобы исключить вопросы типа Вашего от лиц не понимающих разницу между "где" и "куда". Или вам неизвестно, что соцсети - это сокращение от социальных сетей.