# Сеть — с прописной?

Tags: орфоэпия, прописная-строчная

На сайте среди массы примеров со строчной (*В сети мне попадались ресурсы… Натолкнулась в сети на спор… В сети стали появляться такие вот перлы… Порывшись в сети, с удовольствием убедился…*) обнаружился лишь один — с прописной: «…из-за нескольких отрицательных ответов в Сети».

Напрашивается вопрос: право большинство или неправо? И, попутно, ещё раз про ударение, чтобы не возвращаться к проблеме, — на первой или второй гласной. Как правильно?

Comment: Некоторые соображения по поводу ударения есть на нашем сайте: _В предложном падеже: “в сЕти или в сетИ”?_ https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415543/В-предложном-падеже-в-сЕти-или-в-сетИ.

Comment: Спасибо, мне известно это, однако без учёта ударения разобраться с первым вопросом нельзя. Так нельзя (при строчной) определить с первых слов — о какой сети идёт речь в примере «Порывшись в сети, с удовольствием убедился…». Неполный ответ Arhad это и показывает.

Answer (score -1):

Для выбора написания первой буквы необходимо понять, является ли слово именем собственным или нарицательным.

В данном случае «сеть» — это перифраз от слова «интернет». А «интернет», в свою очередь, означает некую обобщённую среду передачи данных (то есть имя нарицательное), и потому пишется со строчной буквы. Как результат, и слово «сеть» в данном случае необходимо писать со строчной буквы.

*Примечание: слово «интернет» имело бы смысл писать с заглавной буквы, будь это, по примеру Фидонета, необобщающее название конкретной совокупности компьютеров на конкретной территории, пользователи которого образуют сообщество, следующее определённым правилам.*

Comment: Допускается написание слова **Интернет** и с прописной, и со строчной буквы, без каких-либо ограничений на Ваше "имело бы смысл". С учётом этого логика ответа превращается в частную точку зрения.

Comment: @grizzly если вы про http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/28_366, то там, по моему мнению, неправильное сопоставление. [ОТИК](http://www.ispreview.ru/company/278/otik.html), ТИКОРП и прочие — это сети, каждая из которых управляется конкретной компанией-провайдером (ОАО "ОТИК-групп" и "... корпорация", неизвестная даже Гуглу). Интернет же — это объединение не организационное, а техническое (то есть не по регламенту или лицензии, а по соблюдению протоколов взаимодействия железа и программ).

Comment: То есть интернет нарицателен за счёт того, что никому не принадлежит и является всего лишь какой-то совокупностью прямо и косвенно связанного между собой оборудования без границ и ограничений. К слову, фактический синоним слова «интернет» — «межоператорские договорённости». Не будет второго — тут же исчезнет и первое.

Comment: Я просто смотрю в официальные словари, которые у меня под рукой. В словаре Лопатина "Как правильно? С большой буквы или с маленькой?" (2002 г.) допускалось написание слова **Интернет** только с прописной. В орфографическом словаре Лопатина (2013 г.) об этом слове говорится отдельно: "Для слова **интернет**, в соответствии с практикой письма и решением Орфографической комиссии РАН, предложены два варианта — с начальной прописной и со строчной буквой". Я считаю, что в этом случае "отсебятина" не уместна.

Comment: @grizzly, насчёт отсебятины согласен. Именно поэтому я и написал: *«необходимо понять, является ли слово именем собственным или нарицательным»*, так как здесь нет жёстких словарных норм. Так, при сопоставлении, к примеру, с Фидонетом, **Интернет** — это сеть, связанная новой на тот момент идеологией ([WWW](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWW)). То есть во времена упомянутой вами редакции словаря Лопатина его явно обособляли, и потому это было имя собственное. Сейчас же никакой идеологической подоплёки в **интернете** нет, поэтому оно стало в том числе и именем нарицательным (просто сеть).